# What is the symbol ''$\divideontimes$'' (DIVIDE TIMES) for?

Tags: notation

I looked "$\divideontimes$" up on Google and now I know that it's Unicode U+22c7 but when would it be used?

I am guessing that $5 \divideontimes 5 = 25$ and $1$...?

Comment: I've never seen that before, but I'm guessing that it's similar to $\pm$.

Comment: Are you sure that it is even meant to be used in a mathematical context?

Comment: $a\divideontimes b=a~b^{\pm1}$

Comment: @N.Owad No, I'm not even sure but it seems to be composed of mathematical operators.

Comment: Sorry for bumping such an old post, I am just really curious about what type of functions produce numbers that take the form. $⋇n$

Comment: A complex 'root' (zero) of the inverse tetration of $^3x$ is [approx.] $⋇(−0.6782039202617192−0.73487375959523527∗i)$ - (Edit: see my answer below for more in-depth explanation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that @Lucian has the right answer (in the comments to OP):

> $a\divideontimes b=a~b^{\pm1}$

Answer (score 13):

The symbol $\pm$ (produced with `\pm` in LaTeX or MathJax) can be used when the underlying [group structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) is **additive**, such as the group of real numbers with addition, $(\mathbb{R}, +)$. The symbol $\divideontimes$ (`\divideontimes`) can be used when the group structure is **multiplicative**, such as the group of positive-real numbers with multiplication, $(\mathbb{R}_{>0}, \cdot)$.

#### Use in statistics

A prominent application of the symbols is in descriptive statistics, where they are used to express *confidence intervals* and *error bars*. For example, if a random variable is **normally distributed**, the expression
$$
\mu_\text{ar} \pm \sigma_\text{ar}
$$
tells you that about $68.27 \%$ of the data are between $\mu_\text{ar} - \sigma_\text{ar}$ and $\mu_\text{ar} + \sigma_\text{ar}$. Here, $\mu_\text{ar}$ is the **arithmetic mean** and $\sigma_\text{ar}$ is the **arithmetic standard deviation**. Similarly, if a random variable is **log-normally distributed**, the expression
$$
\mu_\text{geo} \divideontimes \sigma_\text{geo}
$$
tells you that about $68.27 \%$ of the data are between $\frac{\mu_\text{geom}}{\sigma_\text{geo}}$ and $\mu_\text{geo} \cdot \sigma_\text{geo}$. Here, $\mu_\text{geo}$ is the **geometric mean** and $\sigma_\text{geo}$ is the **geometric standard deviation** (e.g., [Limpert et al, 2001](http://stat.ethz.ch/~stahel/lognormal/bioscience.pdf)).

Comment: Note that the paper you mentioned uses $^\times /$ instead of this symbol.

Answer (score 6):

Note that the root of a number *can* yield a $±$ result

Perhaps the inverse [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) (`super-root`) of a **specific type** of number *can* yield a $⋇$ result

---

$±n$ *really* means     $0+n$     *or*     $0-n$

$⋇n$ would mean     $x*n$     *or*     $x/n$    (I would assume $x=1$)

---

That **"specific type"** of number (for applying a super-root to) is probably between -n and +n IMO (where n is the number being tetrated to (i.e. <sup>n</sup>a), I'd also hypothesize that most solutions take place in the complex plane.)

---

A very trivial (and boring) example of a super-root creating one of these numbers would be the inverse of the tetration, <sup>2</sup>x where <sup>2</sup>x=1

> <sup>2</sup>x=1
>
> *aka*      x<sup>x</sup>=1
>
> *therefor*      x=$⋇1$      because      (1/n)<sup>(1/n)</sup>=1      and     
>   (1*n)<sup>(1*n)</sup>=1      when n is 1

Again, I know that's a super boring example, I'm curious if anyone can find any values of actual intrigue ***(Edit: Found, scroll to bottom)***, I tried using Wolfram alpha with `x^x^x=(1/x)^(1/x)^(1/x)` but it timed out.

Just looking at the graph of <sup>3</sup>x (or `x^x^x`) makes it seem like there should be values that create $⋇$ numbers.

[image]

It seems the inverse tetration of <sup>3</sup>x, while $⋇1$ is valid, also has the complex solution $≈⋇(-0.6782039202617192-0.73487375959523527*i)$... (Along with many others). Neat! Glad Wolfram Alpha has improved over the years! **(2018 edit)**

> x<sup>x<sup>x</sup></sup>=(1/x)<sup>(1/x)<sup>(1/x)</sup></sup>
>
> x ≈ $1*(-0.6782039202617192-0.73487375959523527*i)$
>
> x ≈ $1 / (-0.6782039202617192-0.73487375959523527*i)$
>
> therefore
>
> x ≈ $⋇(-0.6782039202617192-0.73487375959523527*i)$

Answer (score 1):

a^(b±c) = a^b⋇a^c

I have often wondered if this symbol is good for anything non-exotic. Perhaps this is an example.