# Symbol for multiply divide, equivalent of plus minus?

Tags: notation, terminology

Is there a symbol for multiply or divide, which acts like the $\pm$ symbol?

Comment: See also: [What is the symbol ''$\divideontimes$'' (DIVIDE TIMES) for?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/954186/409)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can go with $a\cdot b^{\pm1}$, though I would generally recommend emancipation from $\pm$.